# Angular ui grid double click event setup

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

So I'm trying to get my Angular UI Grid to register a double click event on an entire row to open up a modal.  I can start with a toastr toast and go from there though.  This is the closest I've come based on various demos and examples online, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Controller:

```
$scope.gridHandlers = {
  onDblClick: function(rowItem){
    toastr.success(rowItem, 'Row Item:')
  }
}
$scope.gridOptions = {
  onRegisterApi : function(gridApi){
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi
  },
  data: $scope.customerList,
  enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
  enableRowSelection: true,
  enableSelectAll: false,
  multiSelect: false,
  noUnselect: true,
  rowTemplate: '<div ng-dblclick="getExternalScopes().onDblClick(row)" external-scopes="gridHandlers" ng-repeat=\"(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name\" class=\"ui-grid-cell\" ng-class=\"{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }\" ui-grid-cell></div>',
  columnDefs : [
  {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
   ...etc
  {name: 'status_name', displayName: 'Status', width: '11%', type: 'string'}
]
```

View:

```
<div class="large-12 cols" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection external-scopes="gridHandlers">
```

I've tried using the grid.appScope methods they talk about and everything else, but I just can't get it to work.  Where am I here, totally off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`grid.appScope` did work for me. Please see the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4KThe4upPwthyf5HhE1c?p=preview)  (Double click on any row to see the row data)

Comment: I know this is an older post. but anyways, i followed your guide (which worked, thanks!!!), but I lost a piece of functionality, due to the way the row template was set up.  Now, when I click the 'check' at the left of the grid, the row no longer highlights. Did you experience something similar?