# Added custom row template to ui-grid but lost row highlight functionality

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I followed [this stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112952/angular-ui-grid-double-click-event-setup) to capture a double-click event on my grid. Interestingly though, my grid no longer highlights rows whose check-box's have been selected, as outlined in the gif below
[image: broken highliter gif]

Before I added the row template, everything was fine and worked correctly, as seen in the gif below
[image: gif of working highlighter]

Here is the row template code:

Controller:

```
function rowTemplate() {
   return '<div ng-dblclick="grid.appScope.rowDblClick(row)" >' +
     ' <div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + \'-\' + col.uid + \'-cell\'" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }" role="{{col.isRowHeader ? \'rowheader\' : \'gridcell\'}}" ui-grid-cell></div>' +
     '</div>';
}
```

As part of `$scope.gridOptions`:

```
 , rowTemplate: rowTemplate()
```

Inside `$scope.gridOptions`

```
        $scope.rowDblClick = function(row) {
          console.log('double click event');

          var thisRow = gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows() //gets the clicked row object
          $log.log(thisRow);

          $('.item').on('click', function(){

            //if user clicks on grid tab, should go to grid view else go to patient view
            if ($(this).hasClass('not')){
              console.log('item has .not')
              $state.go('list.patient.patient-information');
            } else {
              console.log('item has .grid')
              $state.go('list.grid');
            }
            //
            $('.item').css('cssText', 'border-radius: 0px !important; background-color: #4B6A89; font-family: Roboto; font-size: 14px; color: white; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: 1.5px; text-transform: uppercase;')
            $(this).closest('.item').css('cssText', 'border-radius: 0px !important; color: #4B6A89; background-color: white; font-family: Roboto; font-size: 14px; color: #4B6A89; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: 1.5px; text-transform: uppercase;');
          });
          //after a 2click, deselect the row, so a user can edit another cell
          $scope.gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows();
        };
```

UPDATE: when I remove the `<div ng-dblclick="grid.appScope.rowDblClick(row)" >` from the template, the line highlight comes back (although I lose the double click functionality

Comment: Can you provide working example? https://jsbin.com or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved after much trial and error!

The problem started when I added the `ng-dblclick` option for grid rows with the suggested syntax:

```
function rowTemplate() {
  return '<div ng-dblclick="grid.appScope.rowDblClick(row)" >' +
            ' <div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + \'-\' + col.uid + \'-cell\'" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }" role="{{col.isRowHeader ? \'rowheader\' : \'gridcell\'}}" ui-grid-cell></div>' +
         '</div>';
}
```

I simply removed the `div` that the `ng-dblclick` was in, and moved it into the main row template div so it now looks like this:

```
function rowTemplate() {
  return ' <div ng-dblclick="grid.appScope.rowDblClick(row)" ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + \'-\' + col.uid + \'-cell\'" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }" role="{{col.isRowHeader ? \'rowheader\' : \'gridcell\'}}" ui-grid-cell></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue before.

Apparently, when we add the outside div for double-click, it messes up the CSS for highlighting. So in your example, on selecting the checkbox, row gets selected, but the highlighting doesn't happen.

Solution for this is:

Row Template:

```
  function rowTemplate() {
    return '<div ng-dblclick="grid.appScope.rowDblClick(row)" >' +
                 '  <div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader}"  ui-grid-cell></div>' +
                 '</div>';
   }
```

And add CSS for that specific grid, adding Grid Id or style:

```
 #gridStyle .ui-grid-row.ui-grid-row-selected > [ui-grid-row] .ui-grid-cell {
    background-color: #c9dde1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[My plunker working sample](http://embed.plnkr.co/aVSv7St1wqJzI7W6tyz1/)

```
function rowTemplate() {
    return '<div ng-dblclick="grid.appScope.rowDblClick(row)" >' +
        '  <div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }"  ui-grid-cell></div>' +
        '</div>';
                                                      }
```

css:

```
/* --- ui-grid ------- row hover highlight ----- */

.ui-grid-row:hover .ui-grid-cell {
 background-color: #ff8476;  
}


/* ==== both works ===== */
/*
 .ui-grid-row:nth-child(odd):hover .ui-grid-cell{background:red}
 .ui-grid-row:nth-child(even):hover .ui-grid-cell{background:red}
*/

 /* --- End ----- ui-grid ------- row hover highlight ----- */
```